# $\sum_{p|q_n} (\log p)^\alpha\sim n(\log n)^\alpha, n\to\infty $, where $q_n:=\prod_{j\leq n}p_j$

Tags: analytic-number-theory

Let $\alpha \in (0,1)$ and let $p_j$ be the sequence of primes and let $q_n:=\prod_{j\leq n}p_j$. Prove that
$$
      \sum_{p|q_n} (\log p)^\alpha
      \sim n(\log n)^\alpha
      \qquad n\to\infty
$$

I am stuck here. Most what I proved is that $\sum_{p|q} (\log p)^\alpha \leq (\omega(q))^{1-\alpha} (\log q)^\alpha$, and then $\omega(q_n) = n$, but I am not sure if I can use this somehow ($\omega(n) = $ no. of distinct prime divisors of n).  Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Let $x:=p_n$. Then the sum under question equals $\sum_{p\leq x}(\log p)^\alpha$ which upon partial summation is not different to $$\pi(x)(\log x)^\alpha-\alpha\int_1^x\pi(x)\frac{(\log x)^{\alpha-1}}{x}\mathrm{d}x,$$
where $\pi(x)$ denotes the number of primes $p\leq x$. The prime number theorem in the form $\pi(x)=\frac{x}{\log x}(1+o(1))$ shows that the previous quantity is $$(1-\alpha) x(\log x)^{\alpha -1}(1+o(1)).$$
This can be proved either by using the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of the limit of a sequence or any weak quantitative form of the prime number theorem. In order to express the final answer in terms of $n$ we observe that $$x=p_n=n(\log n)(1+o(1))\Rightarrow \log x \sim \log n$$ so that $$ (1-\alpha) x(\log x)^{\alpha -1}=(1-\alpha) n (\log n)^{\alpha}.$$ Is it possible that the leading factor $1-\alpha$ is missing from your question ?

Comment: I just rechecked the exercise and no, there is not $1-\alpha$ in front.

Comment: could i please ask for the source ?

Comment: The source is a part of an exercise in my professor's notes for a course in Analytic Number Theory. Where he got it from I have no idea. Sorry. If I make any progress I'll report back. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I agree something is missing somewhere, for example in the case of $\alpha=1$ one should have the asymptotic $\sim x$ and not $0$. I suspect that the problem lies in the asymptotic evaluation of $\int_1^x (\log x)^{\alpha-2} dx$.